# Using Smack to get rosters from ejabberd No response received within reply timeout

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Our XMPP server is using Ejabberd. We have three clients connect to the servers for the chat application. They are IOS, Android and Web. Web and IOS can get the chat history from the server without any problem.

However in the Android, we failed to fetch the message history using Smack.
User is able to send a message to the server over XMPP connection, but it's jut not able to receive the message. It's always timeout no matter how big we set the timeout. After the timeout then the server will return the result.

Please see the code below on how we implemented the code for loading the chat history.

```
public void loadArchiveMessages(Jid jid, XMPPWebSocketConnection xmppTcpConnection) {
        try {
            MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(xmppTcpConnection);
            MamManager.MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.queryArchive(null, 2, null, null, jid, null);


            List<Forwarded> forwardedMessages = mamQueryResult.forwardedMessages;
            Iterator<Forwarded> forwardedIterator = forwardedMessages.iterator();
            while (forwardedIterator.hasNext()) {
                Forwarded forwarded = forwardedIterator.next();
                Stanza stanza = forwarded.getForwardedStanza();
                if (stanza instanceof org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message) {
                    String messageId = stanza.getStanzaId();
                    connection.sendStanzaInternal(stanza);
                }
            }
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the exceptions we got.

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 30000ms (~30s). Waited for response using: IQReplyFilter: iqAndIdFilter (AndFilter: (OrFilter: (IQTypeFilter: type=error, IQTypeFilter: type=result), StanzaIdFilter: id=YXCI3-31)), : fromFilter (OrFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): otsuka.tungdao.com)).
    08-15 09:15:21.100 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaCollector.nextResultOrThrow(StanzaCollector.java:253)
    08-15 09:15:21.100 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaCollector.nextResultOrThrow(StanzaCollector.java:208)
    08-15 09:15:21.101 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager.discoverInfo(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:540)
    08-15 09:15:21.101 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager.discoverInfo(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:506)
    08-15 09:15:21.101 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager.supportsFeatures(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:701)
    08-15 09:15:21.101 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager.serverSupportsFeatures(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:678)
    08-15 09:15:21.101 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager.serverSupportsFeatures(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:672)
    08-15 09:15:21.102 28911-28945/com.otsuka.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.disco.ServiceDiscoveryManager.serverSupportsFeature(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:667)
```

We have tried to search for solutions but to no avail.

Comment: try printing logs for smack and check if your iq-xml matches with the one generated by ios or web